# How to focus every <tr> on table

Tags: html

I would like to parse each `<tr>` in my table.

How can i set on a array the content of each

**My Table :**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">1</td>
    <td class="post">B</td> 
    <td class="url">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">2</td>
    <td class="post">E</td> 
    <td class="url">F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking; please improve your question.

Comment: which language and where is your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function each() with Jquery.
[Jquery each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)